# Automatically upload assets to S3 without assets_sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I just did my first deploy to Heroku and besides my images, the assets work.  I was reading about how to move the assets to s3 (and then cache them with cloudfront) when I found this gist:

[https://gist.github.com/schneems/9374188](https://gist.github.com/schneems/9374188/)
"I hate asset_sync"

> Using asset sync can cause failures, is difficult to debug, un-needed, and adds extra complexity. Don't use it. Instead use https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn

The problem is, I can't find how to sync assets automatically like the gem does.  Whats the best alternative to using the asset_sync gem?

Comment: What don't you understand about the use of cloudfront?

Comment: How do you sync your assets automatically to s3 without asset_sync?

Comment: Did you find a way to do that? I have the same issue...

Comment: @FrederickCheung Would be awesome if you could shed some light, clearly me and a few folks have the same question about this

Answer (score 0):

Although an old question, in case anyone finds this question and is hoping for an answer here are my own findings.

Cloudfront has, for some time now, allowed users to set an `origin` value on their configuration. You want to set that to your application host. If you were deploying to a site accessible via `https://myapp.com` then you would use that as your Cloudfront `origin`. Then any cache misses from Cloudfront will route to your application layer at `https://myapp.com`, appending whatever path info is present in the request (e.g. `/assets/css/whatever.css`. This means that your application must be able to serve these static assets. If it can, then you're all set. If not, check the Rails guide for how to enable that.

**Caveat**! You *cannot* use a non-publicly-accessible URL for the `origin`. What does that mean? If you are provisioning your own pre-production application instances that are hidden behind a VPC, for example, then you cannot use those instances for your `origin`. Cloudfront cannot be granted special access to your instances. There's a workaround if you read Cloudfront's documentation on [serving private content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html); basically you make your application publicly-accessible to anyone with the appropriate links but you enforce application-level constraints to disallow access to anyone not using a specially signed URL or cookie.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but the answers here are not satisfying. The gist and articles linked do not intend to say the asset_sync gem is bad. The article intends to say you shouldn't be serving your assets from anywhere (S3 or not) but your application. Uploading your assets anywhere runs into the same issues mentioned in the gist, no matter if you're using this particular gem or not.

The suggestion is serving your assets from your application and then use a CDN such as Cloudfront to to ease the load on your server. You do not need to upload anything to Cloudfront. Instead, Cloudfront will ask your application for assets on-demand and cache automatically.

However, Cloudfront (or any CDN) do not address all use cases of asset_sync. If you're running into slug size issues and you've already cleaned repos and unnecessary dependencies, you might still need to use asset_sync to get your slug under 500MB and keep Heroku happy. Of course you can forego asset_sync and use a custom implementation to upload to S3 (or anywhere else).